# How to get file timestamps at maximum resolution?

Tags: c, linux

`man 2 stat` shows that the values `st_atime`, `st_mtime` and `st_ctime` returned in the `struct stat` are of type `time_t`, that has seconds resolution. How to get those same values in higher resolution, maybe as `struct timespec` or `struct timeval`, or just the missing subsecond part?

I need this for a C++ on Linux, but I am tagging with C too because I think the answer will probably be the same for both languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the NOTES section of `man 2 stat`:

```
   Since kernel 2.5.48, the stat structure supports nanosecond resolution  for  the  three  file  timestamp  fields.   Glibc
   exposes the nanosecond component of each field using names of the form st_atim.tv_nsec if the _BSD_SOURCE or _SVID_SOURCE
   feature test macro is defined.  These fields are specified in POSIX.1-2008, and, starting with version 2.12,  glibc  also
   exposes  these  field  names if _POSIX_C_SOURCE is defined with the value 200809L or greater, or _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined
   with the value 700 or greater.  If none of the aforementioned macros are defined, then the nanosecond values are  exposed
   with names of the form st_atimensec.  On file systems that do not support subsecond timestamps, the nanosecond fields are
   returned with the value 0.
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind even if it's at nanosecond resolution is that you might no get nanosecond accuracy on your hardware. For instance, I believe the typical Intel hardware is only accurate to around 1 msec, so even though you'll get a value back in so many nanoseconds, you generally can't trust below 1 msec.